# Why will my angularJS login form view not display?

Tags: php, angularjs, angular-ui-router

For some reason the view in my index.html will not display my login.html view at all. May be a routing issue. I don't really understand how to use the routing but I think I'm doing it right.

**index.html**

Comment:

The index.html will hold the ng-app named app and I will switch views depending on what my app is currently doing. By default, the idea is to ALWAYS show the login screen(view: login.html) with a message at the bottom of that view to link to a register view(view: register.html). After a user logs in, the view will change to a user screen showing an inbox of chat messages(This has yet to be implemented but I would love some advice because I just started angularJS). If a user clicks on the register link to bring the user to the register view(view: register.html), they will have the opportunity to register.

Currently my issue is the login form view does not show automatically when I navigate to https://linus.highpoint.edu/~tferguson/research_project/app/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
   <head>
      <script src="../angular-1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="../angular-1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script>
      <script src="controller.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="header">
         <h1>My AngularJS App</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="mainBody">
         <h1>Body of AngularJS App</h1>
         <div ng-view>
            <!-- 
               The login view will be here by default to force login.
               login.html holds this form.

               Once user provides a valid login, I want the view to 
               change to an inbox for messages for a chat app between
               users that can register and stored in a database accessed
               through php.
               Still working on this part.
            -->
         </div>
      </div>

      <div id="footer">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**login.html**

Comment:

This view should show by default on index.html ng-view div. But it doesn't, **I suspect it is because of my controller.js file and that I may be routing incorrectly.**

```
<div id="login" ng-controller="loginCtrl">
   <form name="loginForm">
      Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" ng-model="user.username" required=""/>
      <br />
      <div ng-show="loginForm.$submitted || loginForm.username.$touched">
         <span ng-show="loginForm.username.$error.required">Enter your username/email.</span>
         <span ng-show="loginForm.username.$error.email">This is not a valid email.</span>
      </div>
      Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" ng-model="user.password" required=""/>
      <br />
      <div ng-show="loginForm.$submitted || loginForm.password.$touched">
         <span ng-show="loginForm.password.$error.required">Enter your password.</span>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" ng-click="checkLogin()">Login</button>
      <span>{{ loginMsg }}</span>
   </form>
   <a href="#register">Register</a>
</div>
```

**register.html**

Comment:

Probably not neccesary to show this view but I think it helps provide some context on how exactly my app is supposed to work.

```
<div id="register" ng-controller="registerCtrl">
   <form name="registerForm">
      First Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" ng-model="new_user.FirstName" required=""/>
      <br />
      <div ng-show="registerForm.$submitted || registerForm.FirstName.$touched">
         <span ng-show="registerForm.FirstName.$error.required">Enter your First Name.</span>
      </div>

      Last Name: <input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName" ng-model="new_user.LastName" required=""/>
      <br />
      <div ng-show="registerForm.$submitted || registerForm.LastName.$touched">
         <span ng-show="registerForm.LastName.$error.required">Enter your username/email.</span>
      </div>

      Username(Your Email): <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" ng-model="new_user.Email" required=""/>
      <br />
      <div ng-show="registerForm.$submitted || registerForm.Email.$touched">
         <span ng-show="registerForm.Email.$error.required">Enter your username/email.</span>
         <span ng-show="loginForm.Email.$error.email">This is not a valid email.</span>
      </div>

      Password: <input type="password" name="Pass" id="Pass" ng-model="new_user.Pass" required=""/>
      <br />
      <div ng-show="registerForm.$submitted || registerForm.Pass.$touched">
         <span ng-show="registerForm.Pass.$error.required">Enter your password.</span>
      </div>

      Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="Pass2" id="Pass2" ng-model="new_user.Pass2" required=""/>
      <br />
      <div ng-show="registerForm.$submitted || registerForm.Pass2.$touched">
         <span ng-show="registerForm.Pass2.$error.required">Confirm your password.</span>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" ng-click="register()">Register</button>
      <span>{{ registerMsg }}</span>
   </form>
   <a href="#login">Login</a>
</div>
```

**controller.js**

Comment:

**I think my routing is incorrect here.** I am still new to angularJS and hoping I could get some help on what I'm doing incorrectly and how to fix it. In my controllers I also change the $location so this could also be a suspect. Other suspect portions of code would be the links at the bottom of login.html and register.html views. Basically suspecting anything where I fiddle with routing and location.

Hope I'm right.

```
// Global
var checkVar;

// Apps
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
   $routeProvider
      .when("/", {templateUrl: "login.html", controller: "loginCtrl"})
      .when("/register", {templateUrl: "register.html", controller: "registerCtrl"})
      .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/index.html" });
});

// Controllers
app.controller("loginCtrl", function($scope, $location) {
   $scope.checkLogin = function () {
      $.post(
         "login.php",
         {
            "Email" : $scope.username,
            "Pass" : $scope.password
         },
         function (resJSONdata) {
            var resData = $.parseJSON(resJSONdata);
            if(resData.code == "1") {
               // Go to messages.
               $location.path("/user");
            }
            if(resData.code == "2") {
               $scope.loginMsg = resData.msg;
            }
         }
      )
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

relace this

```
.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/index.html" });
```

with this,

```
.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });
```

because your login route is "`/`" not "`index.html`"

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. :( Any other ideas?